# Unsure how to rewrite htacess to include 301 redirects... (Multiple RewriteEngine ons?)

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am VERY novice on this, having used 301 redirects for other websites a few times. This time, the website has an existing htaccess file that has some "bad bots" directives. Here is a sample (it's a LOOOONG list of bots):

```
Options -Indexes
# BEGIN Refuse Bad Bot
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ".*SemrushBot.*" [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ".*AhrefsBot.*" [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ".*ZyBorg.*"
    RewriteRule ".*" "-" [F]
</IfModule>
# END Refuse Bad Bot
```

I want to keep this and add 301 redirects.  Should I add another RewriteEngine on (esp since the first one SEEMS (to this novice) to be within an IF/THEN statement that won't apply to my 301's.

I assume I should do the following, but not sure if this is correct:

```
Options -Indexes
# BEGIN Refuse Bad Bot
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ".*SemrushBot.*" [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ".*AhrefsBot.*" [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ".*ZyBorg.*"
    RewriteRule ".*" "-" [F]
</IfModule>
# END Refuse Bad Bot

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Redirect 301 /old-page-1/ https://www.example.com/new-page-1/
Redirect 301 /old-page-2/ https://www.example.com/new-page-2/
Redirect 301 /old-page-3/ https://www.example.com/new-page-3/
```

Any help would be appreciated.

** ALSO: I think it is better not to include "/index.html" at the end of the 301's (old or new) for better results?  Did I read that correctly somewhere?

"I'm a designer, not a programmer, Jim!" – Dr. L McCoy

Comment: Wrapping this in `<IfModule ...>` only prevents that Apache will throw errors when the mod_rewrite module is not available, and it therefor doesn't know these directives. But in that case neither the existing or your new code would do anything. Unless you want to write code that is prepared to run in multiple different setups with different modules available, using it is rather superfluous to begin with - if you know your system won't work properly without it, then you kinda _have to_ run it on a system where this _is_ available anyway.